# STM32: I2C works only sometimes with Interrupts

Tags: stm32, i2c, interrupts, dma

I'm working on a little project where I need to read the HMC 5983 Sensor with I2C from a STM32F103RB Board.

When I tested the sensor with the Hal_I2C_Master_Transimt, everything worked fine. I could restart this program a thousand times, and it worked every time:

```
while (1) {

         Kompass_buffer[0] = 0x03;
         RET = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, Kompass_ADDR, Kompass_buffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
         if (RET != HAL_OK) {
         Error = I2C1->SR2;
         sprintf((char*) Serial_buffer, "Error Transmit %i \r\n", Error);
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) Serial_buffer, strlen((char*) Serial_buffer), 200);
         }
         RET = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, Kompass_ADDR, Kompass_buffer, 6, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
         if (RET != HAL_OK) {
         Error = I2C1->SR2;
         sprintf((char*) Serial_buffer, "Error Receiver %i \r\n", Error);
         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) Serial_buffer, strlen((char*) Serial_buffer), 200);
         }
         Kompass_X = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[0]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[1];
         Kompass_Z = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[2]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[3];
         Kompass_Y = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[4]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[5];
         Kompass_print();

         HAL_Delay(200);
```

But ass soon as I want to use I2C with Interrupt or DMA, the Output is sometimes 0 or 740, and I need to restart the program until it works.
I know about the busy flag problem with these boards, but why does it work without interrupts?

I modified the program so that it will print out the SR2 and SR1 Register (in binary) with the Output:

```
while (1) {
        Sr1 = I2C1->SR1;
        Sr2 = I2C1->SR2;
        X = Kompass_X;

        itoa(Sr1, Sr1_buf, 2);
        itoa(Sr2, Sr2_buf, 2);

        sprintf((char*) Serial_buffer, "X: %i  SR1: %s  SR2: %s \r\n", X, Sr1_buf, Sr2_buf);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) Serial_buffer, strlen((char*) Serial_buffer), 200);

        HAL_Delay(500);
}
////Interrupts/////
void HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    RET = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_DMA(&hi2c1, Kompass_ADDR, Kompass_buffer, 6);
}
void HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    Kompass_X = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[0]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[1];
    Kompass_Z = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[2]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[3];
    Kompass_Y = ((int16_t) Kompass_buffer[4]) << 8 | Kompass_buffer[5];
    Kompass_buffer[0] = 0x03;
    RET = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, Kompass_ADDR, Kompass_buffer, 1);
}
```

Ant the Output was this when it worked:

[image]

And this when it didn't:

[image]

I hope someone can help me.
Best regards

Comment: What else is going on in the system? Also, nothing triggers your DMA transaction, you are still running on polling mode in main loop. And it can't be combined with DMA mode in the background. And reading the status registers while transaction is ongoing may disturb the transaction, these must only be read when safe to do so.

Comment: It does run in DMA Mode, I just didn't copy and paste the DMA start. Also, what exactly do you mean with safe to read the register? Should I read them after the interrupt was triggered? I think nothing else is going on in the background, only the I2C DMA interrupts.